# Where is Nautilus in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, nautilus, files

Where is Nautilus in Ubuntu 13.10?

I see only Files app which is similar but lacks some Nautilus features, especially on right-click menu. Can it be installed along official Files app?

I was also unable to install nautilus-scripts in Files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files is nautilus, just under a different name. For some reason nautilus devs have removed a lot of features in the latest release hence the lack of proper right click menu and script support. If you want the old nautilus back I would suggest installing "nemo", a fork of the old version by the guys at linux mint. To do this run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

In a terminal. The nemo app will them be accessible from the dash.

Comment: Funny I can open it from console but not from the Dash

Comment: @ubuntico Weird... it's launcher may also just be called "files". Try searching files in the dash, and see if 2 programs appear, then click both of them until you find the right one.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer doesn't mention that you can still install nautilus scripts without installing any forks of nautilus and I would recommend to stay with the Ubuntu versions.

Just put your scripts into `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` and make them executable with `chmod +x SCRIPT_PATHS`. Finally restart nautilus with `nautilus -q`.

If you prefer to do it without the terminal:

- move the scripts to the above location (might require to show hidden files, that's Ctrl+H)
- select the scripts, right click
- choose Properties -> Permissions
- check "allow executing file as program".
- logout